# Formatting [object HTMLElement] to variable string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using this code here to select the clicked on element has console logging anything other than the `targetElement` produces a `[object HTMLElement]`. Is there a possible simple method to produce a string result? Javascript or Jquery.

```
if (document.addEventListener ){
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log(targetElement);
    });
} else if (document.attachEvent) {    
    document.attachEvent("onclick", function(){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log(targetElement);
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "simple"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `targetElement.outerHTML`

```js
if (document.addEventListener ){
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log(targetElement.outerHTML);
    });
} else if (document.attachEvent) {    
    document.attachEvent("onclick", function(){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log(targetElement.outerHTML);
    });
}
```

If you want to get that element only(not inner html) clone that node and set innerHTML to empty

```js
 if (document.addEventListener ){
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
         
           var newELement = targetElement.cloneNode();
         newELement.innerHTMl="";
         console.log(newELement.outerHTML);
     
    });
} else if (document.attachEvent) {    
    document.attachEvent("onclick", function(){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
         
           var newELement = targetElement.cloneNode();
         newELement.innerHTMl="";
         console.log(newELement.outerHTML);
    });
}
```

Comment: When testing the code in the console in order to click an element, it seems to remove the surrounding tags and attributes. Is there any way to preserve the entire value to string?

Comment: @Pleb Use outerhtml instead of inner html.Updated snippet

Comment: While this maybe good for certain parts, it leaves extreme redundant information for particular parts such as clicking on the background. Where the object through console leaves `<div class="container">...</div>`, the entire code of the page prints which is quite a bit much. Though it does have it all within the "...", is it possible for it to simply console `<div class="container> </div>` for example ?

Comment: @Pleb Please check the second snippet.If you are looking for that

Comment: This one unlike the code I've provided, I cannot seem to be able to run it within the console for the clicked element? Once ran in the console, I seem to get `Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`

Comment: @Pleb  Please look at  the second snippet

Comment: @Pleb  Was this not helpful?